# filter list of dictionaries using multiple conditions

Tags: python, list, iteration, filtering

I want to filter the list data based on the name and order. The output should look as follows:

- After filtering, it should give the name of `'abc'` because all orders are `'buy'` in every dictionary which has `name = 'abc'`.
- Not `'xyz'` and `'dfg'` as there are some orders which have `'sell'` in them.

In short I want output should be that name which don't have `'sell'` in any of the dictionary
eg.

- `{'name': 'abc', 'order':'Buy', 'quantity': 25252},{'name': 'abc', 'order':'Buy', 'quantity': 24424}`,
  and
- `{'name': 'abc', 'order':'Buy', 'quantity': 255252}`

don't have sell order, so the output should be only `'abc'`.

**Input**

```
data = [
    {'name': 'abc', 'order':'Buy', 'quantity': 25252},
    {'name': 'xyz', 'order':'Buy', 'quantity': 4444},
    {'name': 'dfg', 'order':'sell', 'quantity': 254242252},
    {'name': 'xyz', 'order':'sell', 'quantity': 25224252},
    {'name': 'abc', 'order':'Buy', 'quantity': 24424},
    {'name': 'dfg', 'order':'sell', 'quantity': 2424},
    {'name': 'abc', 'order':'Buy', 'quantity': 255252},
]
```

**Desired Output**

```
'abc'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the most simple approach I could think of

```
sell_list = []
res = []

# This loop will check for all the items that have order = sell
for i in data:
    if i['order'] == 'sell' and i['name'] not in sell_list:
        sell_list.append(i['name'])

for i in data:
    # Checking if the item has order = buy and check if it already have order = sell 
    if i['order'] == 'Buy' and i['name'] not in sell_list and i['name'] not in res:
        res.append(i['name'])


print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is your list, then:

```py
sell_set = {d["name"] for d in data if d["order"] == "sell"}

print(
    *{
        d["name"]
        for d in data
        if d["order"] == "Buy" and not d["name"] in sell_set
    }
)
```

Prints:

```
abc
```